# What does the "3" mean in the SELECT hex output of binary(16)?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE user (id binary(16));
INSERT INTO user VALUES (123);

SELECT bin(id) FROM user;
SELECT hex(id) FROM user;
```

The first one prints out `1111011` - 123 in binary, all fine and good.

The second one prints out `31323300000000000000000000000000` - 3 and 1, 3 and 2, 3 and 3, so 123 is rendered as 313233. What's going on?

[image: mysql fiddle screenshot]

Comment: 31 is HEX code of '1' char, 32 is HEX code of '2'... BINARY is STRING datatype, so your argument `123` is converted to string before insertion.

Comment: Oh, this is the answer I was looking for! Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to insert the raw binary representation of the decimal integer 123 (`7B` in hexadecimal) you need to arrange the appropriate conversions or, otherwise, MySQL will cast to string:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (UNHEX(CONV(123, 10, 16)));
```

Beware though that MySQL will right-pad with zeros when you insert into a `binary` column:

```
SELECT HEX(id) FROM user;
-- 7B000000000000000000000000000000
```